# search Gmail for xls attachments

Tags: javascript, gmail

with this code I use to save attachment to a shared google drive folder and got notified when a change happen to it by a mail. All is fine as long as I search for pdf attachments. As I set file:xls the messages returned are far more than expected. Not only, the threads returned by the debug are correct, as well as insert the query in the search filed in Gmail, but the getmessages() returned in this case 38 messages (and attachements! And not only xls but also a pdf) of the query parameters. The conversation view is disabled in Gmail, the only match with this attachments is the from: field.
I tried to change the reference data (by adding newer_than), and nothing changed; I changed the for cycle, and nothing changed. Am I missing something really stupid or is this a kind of bug  with xls?

```
function salvataggioTavoloTecnico(){

var folderName = 'tavoloTecnico';

var p = 0;
var f1s= DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next().getFiles();
while (f1s.hasNext()) {
   var f1 = f1s.next();
   p++
} Logger.log(p);
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate()-1);
var n = d.getFullYear() + "/" + addZero(d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + addZero(d.getDate()); 
var query = 'in:anywhere has:attachment filename:XLS newer_than:5d (from:mariano.casillo@mit.gov.it OR from:donato.castigliego@mit.gov.it OR from:luciano.aloia@mit.gov.it)';
    //var query = 'in:anywhere has:attachment filename:xls '+ 'after:'+n+' (from:mariano.casillo@mit.gov.it OR from:donato.castigliego@mit.gov.it OR from:luciano.aloia@mit.gov.it)';
var elenco = GmailApp.search(query);
var quanteMail = elenco.length; Logger.log(quanteMail);
labelName = GmailApp.createLabel('Movimenti - Tavolo tecnico');   
    for (var i = 0 ; i < quanteMail;  i++) {
    //for ( var i in elenco) {
    elenco[i].addLabel(labelName);
    var thr = elenco[i];
    var nn = thr.getMessageCount();
    Logger.log(nn);
    var mesgs = thr.getMessages();
    var www = mesgs.length;
    for(var j = 0 ; j < www ; j ++){
    var attachments = mesgs[j].getAttachments();
    var rrr = attachments.length;
    for(var k = 0 ; k < rrr ; k ++) {
        var attachment = attachments[k];
        var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
        var file = DriveApp.createFile(attachmentBlob);
        DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next().addFile(file);
      }

}
}
var c = 0;
var f2s = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next().getFiles();
while (f2s.hasNext()) {
   var f2 = f2s.next();
   c++
 }

if ( c > p) { GmailApp.sendEmail("me@me.com", " avviso "+folderName, "Un nuovo file è stato aggiunto")};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why the search by code return more messages out of the parameters, but I workaround it by search in the "wrong" messages only those I need by parse the date, like this, and now it works:

......

```
var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
        for ( var i in threads) {
       threads[i].addLabel(labelName);
        var mesgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        var www = mesgs.length;
        for(var j = 0 ; j < www ; j ++){
         if ( mesgs[j].getDate() < d ){} else {
        var attachments = mesgs[j].getAttachments();
        var rrr = attachments.length;

       for(var k = 0 ; k < rrr ; k ++) {
        var attachment = attachments[k];
        var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
        var file = DriveApp.createFile(attachmentBlob);
        DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next().addFile(file);
      }
    }
    }
}
```

.......